# How do I Debug blazor wasm asp.net core hosted on Vscode?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, blazor-webassembly

I create new Project with Blazor wasm asp.net core hosted, so my project have Client,Server,Shared.

I was originally using Visual Studio to develop, But I wanna turn to VSCode, Cause I use Vscode more.

But I get a problem If I set breakpoint on clinet-side code it will work, Sever-side doesn't work.

my code structure is razor ---> clinet-side interface --> API ---> Server-side Controller ---> Server -side interface to Crud product.

Now I wanna debug Server-sdie code but breakpoint not working.

This is my computer SDK

.NET SDK:
Version:   6.0.404
Commit:    be4f3ec411

OS ENV:
OS Name:     Windows
OS Version:  10.0.22621
OS Platform: Windows
RID:         win10-x64
Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.404\

Host:
Version:      7.0.1
Architecture: x64
Commit:       97203d38ba

.NET SDKs installed:
6.0.404 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

and This is my Server-side launchSetting.json

```
{
    "iisSettings": {
      "windowsAuthentication": false,
      "anonymousAuthentication": true,
      "iisExpress": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:30765",
        "sslPort": 44311
      }
    },
    "profiles": {
      "SipposM2.Server": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7295;http://localhost:5036",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      },
      "IIS Express": {
        "commandName": "IISExpress",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

VSC launch.json and Tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch and Debug Standalone Blazor WebAssembly App",
            "type": "blazorwasm",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/SipposM2/Server",
            "browser": "edge",
            "url": "https://localhost:7295",
        },
        {
            "name": "Watch",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/SipposM2/Server",
            "program": "dotnet",
            "args": [
                "watch",
                "--project",
                ".",
                "--verbose" // Let's us confirm browser connects with hot reload capabilities
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "build" // Ensure we don't watch an unbuilt site
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "blazorwasm",
            "request": "attach",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/SipposM2/Server",
            "url": "https://localhost:7295",  // Tell launch where to find site
            "timeout": 120000, // Allows time for the site to launch
        }
    ],
        "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Debug with Hot Reload",
            "configurations": [ "Watch", "Attach" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/SipposM2/Server/SipposM2.Server.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "${workspaceFolder}/SipposM2/Server/SipposM2.Server.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "watch",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "watch",
                "run",
                "--project",
                "${workspaceFolder}/SipposM2/Server/SipposM2.Server.csproj"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I really press F5 Vscode will tell me unbound breakpoint.

I tried to add <DebuggerSupport> and <CopyOutputSymbolsToPublishDirectory> in Server.csproj but it doesn't work.

```
    <DebuggerSupport>true</DebuggerSupport>
    <CopyOutputSymbolsToPublishDirectory>true</CopyOutputSymbolsToPublishDirectory>
```

Comment: Do you want to debug in browser or in backend using VScode?

Comment: useing Vscode to debug

Comment: Hope you got the explanation and how should you proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I get a problem If I set breakpoint on clinet-side code it will
> work, Sever-side doesn't work.

Well, your configuration seems alright. Although in reagrds of visual studio code we require the following extensions:

1. [C# for Visual Studio Code Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp)
2. [Blazor WASM Debugging Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.blazorwasm-companion)

However,currently [standalone Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#vscode) allows browser debugging only. You can check here in our [official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#debug-hosted-blazor-webassembly)

[image]

**Note:** Published, hosted Blazor WebAssembly apps should only enable debugging and copying output symbols when deploying published assets locally. You can check more details here in [warning section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#attach-to-an-existing-debugging-session).

Comment: You are welcome and glad to assist you on this.

Comment: do you know when debugging hosted Blazor WASM applications will be fully supported in VS Code? Judging from internet tutorials, it seems it was possible in .NET 5, but the documentation for .NET 6 and .NET 7 says only browser debugging is possible.

It is frustrating having to rely on Visual Studio for this. Many thanks

Comment: If you add the extension in VScode it should. By the way while you are trying to debug what happening? Have you tried other IDE like visual studio?

Comment: Ah I realized, part of the problem was I thought _"Only browser debugging is supported..."_ meant only debugging through Edge or Chrome DevTools, and not through VS Code. Secondly, I needed to set the `timeout` property in my `launch.json` to longer than the default. I am still trying to understand if it is possible to debug server as well as client code, but I'm making progress. Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1):

It's now Possible to debug a Hosted Application with Blazor Webassembly in VS Code

If you wanna try out, you may create a new Hosted Blazor Webassembly with:

```
dotnet new blazorwasm -ho
```

The LaunchSettings will be automatically configured to debug a Blazor Webassemby

But how to debug both Blazor Webassembly and The Hosted Application (Like controllers and etc) ?

in launch.json, add the following configuration:

```
   "configurations": [
      {
         "name": "Launch and Debug Standalone Blazor WebAssembly App",
         "type": "blazorwasm",
         "request": "launch",
         "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Server",
         "hosted": true,
         "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Server/bin/Debug/net7.0/blazorassemblyhostedTest.Server.dll"
      }
```

The trick is the hosted: true and setting the program DLL pointing to the server dll

You may have to specify the url to listen to:

```
"url": "https://localhost:5031"
```